# SVG rect animation direction bottom to top

Tags: animation, svg

I have the following SVG animation:

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNJYGe

HTML:

```
<div class='batteryIcon'>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 668.3 1108.2">
    <rect class="power" x="100" y="150" width="470" height="880">
      <animate attributeName="height" values="0 ; 880" dur="2.5s" />
    </rect>
    <polygon class="st0" points="444.9,80.7 444.9,15.8 231.2,15.8 231.2,80.7 40.3,80.7 40.3,1080.8 629.3,1080.8 629.3,80.7 "/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.batteryIcon {
  svg {
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
    .st0 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #adadad;
      stroke-width: 20;
      stroke-miterlimit: 5;
    }
    .power {
      fill: #06B67A;
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that the animation goes from _top to bottom instead of **bottom to top**.
I tried to *transform* my rect by CSS and inline attribute, added *rotate* and *direction* attributes and also *keyPoints*. Nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `rect` and animating the `height` you can use a `polygon` and animate the `points` attribute.

```css
.batteryIcon svg {
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
}
.batteryIcon svg .st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #adadad;
  stroke-width: 20;
  stroke-miterlimit: 5;
}
.batteryIcon svg .power {
  fill: #06B67A;
}
```

```html
<div class='batteryIcon'>
      <svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 668.3 1108.2">
       <!--<rect class="power" x="100" y="150" width="470" height="880">
          <animate attributeName="height" values="0 ; 880" dur="2.5s" />
        </rect>-->
        
        <polygon points="100,1030 570,1030 570,150 100,150">
          <animate attributeName="points" values="100,1030 570,1030 570,1030 100,1030 ; 100,1030 570,1030 570,150 100,150" dur="2.5s" />
        </polygon>
       <polygon class="st0" points="444.9,80.7 444.9,15.8 231.2,15.8 231.2,80.7 40.3,80.7 40.3,1080.8 629.3,1080.8 629.3,80.7 "/>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just animate the y value at the same time as the height. You want to finish the y at 150 and it needs to change by 880 so the starting value must be 880 + 150.

```css
svg {
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
}
.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #adadad;
  stroke-width: 20;
  stroke-miterlimit: 5;
}
.power {
  fill: #06B67A;
}
```

```html
<div class='batteryIcon'>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 668.3 1108.2">
    <rect class="power" x="100" y="150" width="470" height="880">
      <animate attributeName="y" values="1030 ; 150" dur="2.5s" />
      <animate attributeName="height" values="0 ; 880" dur="2.5s" />
    </rect>
    <polygon class="st0" points="444.9,80.7 444.9,15.8 231.2,15.8 231.2,80.7 40.3,80.7 40.3,1080.8 629.3,1080.8 629.3,80.7 "/>
  </svg>
</div>
```